# TabBarControllerを初期化したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

アドベンチャーゲームを作っています。
起動時にシナリオ選択画面で複数のシナリオから遊ぶシナリオを選択してゲームを進め、最後まで終わったらシナリオ選択画面に戻って別シナリオを選択してゲームをする、という動作をさせたいです。
storyboardで起動時にシナリオ選択するViewControllerと、ゲームを行うTabBarContoroller配下のViewControllerを作り、シナリオ選択したらセグエでTabBarControllerに遷移して最後までゲームをしたらセグエでシナリオ選択ViewControllerに戻る、という動作はできました。
ここで再度シナリオ選択したら起動時と同じ状態で新しいシナリオで動作するように、セグエでViewControllerに戻る時やTabBarController遷移時にTabBarControllerや配下のViewControllerを全て初期化してしまうような実装はできないでしょうか？
漠然とした質問で申し訳ありませんが、知恵をお貸しください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「なにをどうしたい」という説明はありますが、「なにをこうしたら、ああなってしまう」という説明がありません。そのため、質問者さんがなにを問題にしているか、読者から見えづらい現状です。

Comment: シナリオ選択以降の画面遷移、特にシナリオ選択と TabBarController の間の遷移をどのように実装されているのかが気になります。

OS で用意されているモーダル表示や NavigationController へのプッシュなどを行ったあと、最初の画面に戻ると、普通はそれ以降の ViewController が開放されて、「初期化」されたような状態になると思います。